# Why does this tensorflow code crash?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I've built a toy model for image classification. The program is loosely structured like the [cifar10 tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn). Training starts fine, but eventually the program crashes. I've finalized the graph just in case somewhere ops were being added to it, and in tensorboard it looks great, but without fail it eventually freezes and forces a hard restart (or long wait for an eventual reboot). The exit makes it seem like a GPU memory issue, but the model is small and should fit. If I allocate the full GPU memory (which gives another 4gb), it will still crash.

The data are 256x256x3 images and labels stored in a tfrecords file. The training function code looks like:

```
def train():
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
         global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()
         train_images_batch, train_labels_batch = distorted_inputs(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
         train_logits = inference(train_images_batch)
         train_batch_loss = loss(train_logits, train_labels_batch)
         train_op = training(train_batch_loss, global_step, 0.1)

         merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
         saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
         gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.75)
         sess_config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
         sess = tf.Session(config=sess_config)
         train_summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(
         os.path.join(ROOT, 'logs', 'train'), sess.graph)
         init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

         sess.run(init)
         coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
         threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

         tf.Graph().finalize()
         for i in range(5540):
             start_time = time.time()
             summary, _, batch_loss = sess.run([merged, train_op, train_batch_loss])
             duration = time.time() - start_time
             train_summary_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
             if i % 10 == 0:
                 msg = 'batch: {} loss: {:.6f} time: {:.8} sec/batch'.format(
                 i, batch_loss, str(time.time() - start_time))
                 print(msg)
         coord.request_stop()
         coord.join(threads)
         sess.close()
```

The loss and training op are cross_entropy and the adam optimizer respectively:

```
def loss(logits, labels):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits, name='cross_entropy_per_example')
    xentropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name='cross_entropy')
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', xentropy_mean)
    return xentropy_mean

def training(loss, global_step, learning_rate):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
    return train_op
```

And the batches are generated with

```
 def distorted_inputs(batch_size):
     filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
         ['data/train.tfrecords'], num_epochs=None)
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,
        features={'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                  'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)})
    label = features['label']
    label = tf.cast(label, tf.int32)
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image'], tf.uint8)
    image = (tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255) - 0.5
    image = tf.reshape(image, shape=[256, 256, 3])
    # data augmentation
    image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image)
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    print('filling the queue with {} images ' \
          'before starting to train'.format(MIN_QUEUE_EXAMPLES))
    return _generate_batch(image, label, MIN_QUEUE_EXAMPLES, BATCH_SIZE)
```

and

```
def _generate_batch(image, label,
                    min_queue_examples=MIN_QUEUE_EXAMPLES,
                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE):
    images_batch, labels_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [image, label], batch_size=batch_size,
        num_threads=12, capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * BATCH_SIZE,
        min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
    tf.summary.image('images', images_batch)
    return images_batch, labels_batch
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hey, not really sure what you are asking... what is not working?

Comment: If you are running Windows, you can load the crash dump in windbg and check which module failed.

Comment: The program runs great until it freezes my machine, typically after 800 or more iterations (batch size 64 or 128, doesn't seem to matter). So I suspect a (GPU) memory leak (RAM usage is stable throughout), but where is not clear to me (if that's even the issue). Since AFAIK there is no way to grab detailed GPU memory usage info from/during a tensorflow program run, I'm wondering if those with more tensorflow experience than I see a culprit in my code. I'm still a little unfamiliar with the graph model. If it helps, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, tf 1.0.0, python 3.5, on a Tesla k40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I resolved this. Here's the solution in case it's useful to someone else. TL,DR: it's a hardware issue.

Specifically, it's a PCIe bus error, the same error as that with the most votes [here](http://www.overclock.net/t/1539708/question-for-x99-board-owners-with-nvidia-cards-do-you-see-pcie-bus-errors-please-respond-to-poll). Possibly this is caused by message signalled interrupts being incompatible with the PLX switches, as suggested [here](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/957456/gtx-1080-throwing-bad-tlp-pcie-bus-errors/). Also in that thread is what resolved the issue, setting kernel parameter `pci=nommconf` to disable the msi's.

Between Tensorflow, Torch, and Theano, tf is the only deep learning framework that triggers this issue. Why, I'm not sure.